# Scrolling issues of GridView inside Viewpager inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I am having a layout in which I am using CoordinatorLayout and NestedScrollView. I am using viewpager with 3 tabs in the nested scrollview. I am using fragments for the tabs and in one of the tab I am having Gridview.

So now, gridview scrolling is working inside that fragment only, I want the scrolling in the whole page.

Can you please help me here.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: did u fixed this?